# custom facter which can identify CentOS and Amazon Linux instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, puppet, facter

Is there any facter variable available or I can create a custom facter variable to identify the CentOS and Amazon Instances?

I want to install some utils on CentOS and Amazon Linux instances but not able to find a way to do that using puppet.

Comment: Was this issue researched at all?

Comment: Yes Felix, it was researched, then only posted here. If you think, you can give the right answer or point me to the right URL's. I would really appreciate that and upvote your ans as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the operating system with the fact `operatingsystem`. The two values that you are interested in are `Amazon` and `CentOS`. If you log in to each host and run `facter` you can see what values are reported by each.

Comment: I am using facter-2.2 which give the same value of operatingsystem in amazon linux and centos

Comment: Facter 2.2 should also have different values for the fact `operatingsystem`. What output are you getting?

Comment: Sorry Chris, I am using Facter-2.4 which gives Operatingsystem = CentOS in both amazon linux as well as in CentOS

Answer (score 0):

Must create file /etc/redhat-release containing "CentOS release 7.1